# Trying to derive Age from DOB, and then calculate points, using if..else statements

Tags: javascript, html, date, parseint

I'm trying to derive the users age from DOB using a script, then depending on this age award them points for two areas Federal(f) and Quebec(q) Immigration, as they both calculate age points i have a set of if...else commands to award points and display them in two textboxes.
currently the script for calcualting the points parseInt's the text field that displays the age(this field is populated by the dobtoage script)
heres my code and a [live preview](http://onthemouse.com/files/immi/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Quebec and Federal Immigration Points Calculator</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form">
<p>Your Date of Birth (format:<strong>dd/mm/yyyy</strong>)</p><br />
<input onmouseout="showAge()" name="dob" id="dob" />
<p>Your Age</p><input name="age" type="text" style="font-size: 15px" value="" size="7" readonly>
<INPUT NAME="calc" VALUE="Calculate" TYPE="button" onClick="compute(this.form)"><br />
<input name="rsltf" type="text" style="font-size: 50px" value="" size="20" readonly /><br />
<input name="rsltq" type="text" style="font-size: 50px" value="" size="20" readonly />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function showAge(){ 
var d =document.getElementById('dob').value.split('/'); 
var today=new Date(); 
var bday=new Date(d[2],d[1],d[0]); 
var by=bday.getFullYear(); 
var bm=bday.getMonth()-1; 
var bd=bday.getDate(); 
var age=0; var dif=bday; 
while(dif<=today){ 
var dif = new Date(by+age,bm,bd); 
age++; 
} 
age +=-2 ; 
form.age.value = age; 
} 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function compute(form)
{
var a = parseInt(form.age.value, 10) || 0; 
if (a == 17)
   {
   f = 2; q = 0; 
   }
   else if (a == 53)
   {
   f = 2; q = 0;
   }
   else if (17 > a > 53)
   {
   f = 0; q = 0;
   }
   else if (a == 19)
   {
   f = 6; q = 16;
   }
   else if (a == 51)
   {
   f = 6; q = 0;
   }
   else if (a == 18)
   {
   f = 4; q = 16;
   }
   else if (a == 20)
   {
   f = 8; q = 16;
   }
   else if (a == 50)
   {
   f = 8; q = 0;
   }
   else if (a == 52)
   {
   f = 4; q = 0;
   }
   else if (35 >= a >= 21)
   {
   f = 10; q = 16;
   }
   else if (a == 36)
   {
   f = 10; q = 14;
   }
   else if (a == 37)
   {
   f = 10; q = 12;
   }
   else if (a == 38)
   {
   f = 10; q = 10;
   }
   else if (a == 39)
   {
   f = 10; q = 8;
   }
   else if (a == 40)
   {
   f = 10; q = 6;
   }
   else if (a == 41)
   {
   f = 10; q = 4;
   }
   else if (a == 42)
   {
   f = 10; q = 2;
   }
   else if (a == 43)
   {
   f = 10; q = 0;
   }
   else if (50 >= a >= 44)
   {
   f = 10; q = 0;
   }
form.rsltf.value = f;
form.rsltq.value = q;   
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: my question is why it doesnt work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're calculating age weirdly.

Do this:

```
var today = new Date(); 
var bday = new Date(d[2],d[1],d[0]);
var age = today.getFullYear() - bday.getFullYear();  //If you're born in 1980 then 2011-1980 means you're about 31 years old, this will give you the age if birthday has already passed

if(today.getMonth() < bday.getMonth() || (today.getMonth() == bday.getMonth() && today.getDate() < bday.getDate()))  
{
     age--;  //Reduce age by 1 if birthday hasn't passed
}
```

As to the giant if elseif structure, first I'd break it up into two separate structures.  This allows you to take advantage of ranges in one that aren't available in the other to shorten your overall structure.  The age ranges are so jumbled up in it that I don't really feel like picking through it to construct the appropriate structures.  Might want to take advantage of switch case statements instead of if/elseif/else.

Also, put your functions up in the head where they belong.  Also, you need some error checking on the ShowAge() function in case it's not a valid date.  Also, you need use `getElementById` on the form's id to change it's value in `ShowAge()` at the end, otherwise it has no idea what `form` is.  So, give your form an id and change the end of `ShowAge()` to:

```
document.getElementById('formid').age.value = age;
```

Comment: i'll look into the switch case statements and i've decided to use your code for ShowAge() function, thank you.

Comment: @theatomicdude Also need to use getElementById on the form at the end of ShowAge() to update the age value.  I just added an example.

Comment: Also, seems to be some slight logic error in the age code that I posted that makes it a year below what it should be.

Comment: i dont think getElementbyId is required cos it automatically asumes its the name of the form (which it is) and your code works fine with a little tweeking, thanks again :D

Comment: Still wise to do.  Couldn't get it to change the age field for me until I changed it to using getElementById (using Firebug to change it live) in FireFox.  Besides, what if you wind up with more than one form on the page this script goes on?

Comment: ye, just checked, doesnt owrk in firefox, only in opera, will make tha change, thanks

Comment: Since you're passing the form to the script in `compute()` you shouldn't have to do it there though.